# ¿Por qué al exportar mi base de datos a un archivo CSV no me lo ordena?

Tags: python, csv, sqlite3

```py
def DataBaseExport(self):
    #En esta parte genero el archivo y la ruta para guardarlo
    filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Data Base", "", "CSV (Delimitado por comas)(*.csv);;Documento de texto(*.txt)")
    conexion = sqlite3.connect(self.pathDataBase)  ># hacemos una consulta con nuestra base de datos
    consulta = conexion.cursor()
    consulta.execute('SELECT * FROM Registro')
    registro = consulta.fetchall()
    print(registro)
    if not registro == None:
        if registro:      
    # Aqui   
            with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(filePath)), "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write("id, Nombre, Direccion, Latitud, Longitud, Visible, No_Visitas, Ultima_Visita, Hora_Reunion, Cliente, Contacto, Proyecto")
                for datos in registro:
                #En este apartado es donde genero los datos ordenados
                    file.write(str(datos[0]).replace("\n", "") + "," + str(datos[1]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[2]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[3]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(
                    datos[4]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[5]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[6]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[7]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[8]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[9]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[10]).replace("\n", "") + ',' + str(datos[11]).replace("\n", "") +  "\n")
                    file.close()
                    self.ui.frame_message_error.setStyleSheet(Stylemessage.QFrameSave)
                    self.ui.label_maxumum_8.setText("Satisfactoriamente guardado.")
                    self.toggleMenuError()
    else:
        self.ui.frame_message_error.setStyleSheet(Stylemessage.QFrameMessageError)
        self.ui.label_maxumum_8.setText("No exite ningun registro.")
        self.toggleMenuError()
```

Así me genera los datos:

[image: Así me genera los datos]

Comment: Pregunta tonta: ¿ Porqué no obtienes los datos ya ordenados usando `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: No a lo que me refiero es que los datos de las filas están desagrupados no corresponden con su columna correspondiente